# How to set multi value metadata list field using jquery?

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, jsom, term-store, term-set

How to set multi value metadata list field using jquery?

I am trying to update the vaule by passing term name and term ID.

I am able to save single value but throwing error with multiple values:

```
ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
pList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("list name");
-
-
-
pList.set_item("field_Name", "-1#asd23|d9827562-6f3e-4376-a682- 
 d2283e5b90a9;-1#XYZ|dd6341c9-f279-4723-a894-912bc0d691");
pList.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue by adding missing ; and # as given below:

```
pList.set_item("field_Name", "-1;#asd23|d9827562-6f3e-4376-a682-d2283e5b90a9;#-1;#XYZ|dd6341c9-f279-4723-a894-912bc0d691")
```